# Key Error while upgrading from 20.04 to 20.10

Tags: apt, do-release-upgrade, 20.10

I got this key error and I have no idea how to fix it :(

```
njrm@Pascal:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade

[sudo] password for njrm: 

Checking for a new Ubuntu release

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B] 
                                          
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,338 kB] 
                                                 
Fetched 1,339 kB in 0s (0 B/s)         
                                        
authenticate 'groovy.tar.gz' against 'groovy.tar.gz.gpg' 

extracting 'groovy.tar.gz'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-a4q501zp/groovy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-a4q501zp/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 205, in main
    logdir = setup_logging(options, config)

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-a4q501zp/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 109, in setup_logging

    apt_version = cache['apt'].current_ver.ver_str

KeyError: 'apt'
```